# remove unwanted folder and slashes view in url in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is any way to remove unwanted folder view in url in php, 
Ex: `www.example.com/demo/ver1/index.php`

I need to remove `/demo/ver1` from the url, final result should be 
`www.example.com/index.php`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What PHP framework you're using? What JS Framework you're using? There's a lot we need to know before we can answer this.

Comment: htaccess, and mod rewrite might do what you want.  But we need a lot more information about your systems.

Comment: I am using core PHP, no any kind of frame work. But I can not change it manually if I do this I need to set all kind of path checking and testing